# How to remove dupes from blocks of text

Tags: ruby, perl, awk, sed

What's a smart and easy way to remove dupes within blocks within a file of text. Each block is separated by two newlines.

BEFORE:

```
apple
banana
apple
cherry
cherry

delta
epsilon
delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
delta
```

AFTER:

```
apple
banana
cherry

delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
```

Thanks. Should work on a Mac. Allow unicode. Any shell method/language/command. Dupes are not necessarily consecutive. Bonus if you ignore leading/trailing whitespace, or can use a comma as the delimiter within a record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '!NF{delete seen} !seen[$0]++' file
apple
banana
cherry

delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
```

To **ignore** (as opposed to **remove**) leading/trailing white space with GNU awk for gensub() would be:

```
$ awk '!NF{delete seen} !seen[gensub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"","g")]++' file
```

I've no idea what you mean by `can use a comma as the delimiter within a record` in this context.

Comment: Hi Ed. Wow! That's awesome! I feel like this is so short and elegant that I should have know about it. Perfect, thanks. I can use this a lot.

Comment: Oh, by a comma, I meant to be able to process this format also: apple, banana, apple, banana \n

Comment: This also will remove any items seen from the previous blocks

Answer (score 0):

RUBY!

```
text =<<_
apple
banana
apple
cherry
cherry

delta
epsilon
delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
delta
_

r1 = /
     (?<=\n) # match a newline in a positive lookbehind
     \n      # match a newline
     /x      # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

r2 = /
     (?<=\n) # match a newline in a positive lookbehind
     /x

puts text.split(r1).map { |s| s.split(r2).uniq.join }.join("\n")
  # apple
  # banana
  # cherry

  # delta
  # epsilon

  # apple pie
  # delta
```

The steps:

```
a = text.split(r1)
  #=> ["apple\nbanana\napple\ncherry\ncherry\n",
  #    "delta\nepsilon\ndelta\nepsilon\n",
  #    "apple pie\ndelta\ndelta\n"] 
a.map { |s| s.split(r2) }
  #=> [["apple\n", "banana\n", "apple\n", "cherry\n", "cherry\n"],
  #    ["delta\n", "epsilon\n", "delta\n", "epsilon\n"],
  #    ["apple pie\n", "delta\n", "delta\n"]] 
a.map { |s| s.split(r2).uniq }
  #=> [["apple\n", "banana\n", "cherry\n"],
  #    ["delta\n", "epsilon\n"],
  #    ["apple pie\n", "delta\n"]] 
b = a.map { |s| s.split(r2).uniq.join }
  #=> ["apple\nbanana\ncherry\n",
  #    "delta\nepsilon\n",
  #    "apple pie\ndelta\n"] 
b.join("\n")
  #=> "apple\nbanana\ncherry\n\ndelta\nepsilon\n\napple pie\ndelta\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/\b((\S+)\b.*)\n\2$/\1/;/^$/M!ba' file
```

Store lines in the pattern space (PS) until a blank line or the end of the file. Pattern match on the last line read and previous lines and if they match, remove the last line. If the last line is an empty one (or the end of the file), print all lines held in the PS.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
apple
banana
apple
cherry
cherry

delta
epsilon
delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
delta
```

You can use Ruby's paragraph mode command line switch to have the blank line be a delimiter for each record and set the field separator to be `\n` for each field. Then uniquify each block:

```
$ ruby -00 -F'\n' -lane '$><<$F.uniq.join("\n")<<"\n\n"' file
apple
banana
cherry

delta
epsilon

apple pie
delta
```

Explained:

```
$ ruby -00 -F'\n' -lane '$><<$F.uniq.join("\n")<<"\n\n"'
   ^                                                      # ruby 1.9+ only I think
        ^                                                 # split records by \n\n
            ^                                             # split fields by \n
                   ^                                      # options to:
                                                            -l loop over input
                                                             a auto split
                                                             n don't auto print
                                                             e compile command line
                         ^                                # to STDOUT
                           ^                              # append
                             ^                            # the split fields
                                 ^                        # made uniq
                                     ^                    # join back to a string
                                          ^               # add back the record separator
```

Alternatively, you can use a Ruby hash to count the fields and then just print the keys of the hash:

```
$ ruby -00 -F'\n' -lane 'h=Hash.new(0)
                         $F.each {|f| h[f]+=1 }
                         p h
                         puts h.keys.join("\n")<<"\n\n"
                         ' file
{"apple"=>2, "banana"=>1, "cherry"=>2}
apple
banana
cherry

{"delta"=>2, "epsilon"=>2}
delta
epsilon

{"apple pie"=>1, "delta"=>2}
apple pie
delta
```

(In ruby 1.9+, hashes maintain insertion order -- this will print the words in file order.)

Then if you want to add a `,` to the potential field separators, you can do:

```
$ ruby -00 -F'\n|,' -lane '$><<$F.uniq.join("\n")<<"\n\n"' file
```