# How to remove dupes within lines of delimited text

Tags: awk

What's a smart and easy way to remove dupes (not necessarily consecutive) within delimited items on a line.

BEFORE:

```
apple,banana,apple,cherry,cherry
delta,epsilon,delta,epsilon
apple pie,delta,delta
```

AFTER:

```
apple,banana,cherry
delta,epsilon
apple pie,delta
```

Should work on a Mac. Allow unicode. Any shell method/language/command. Dupes are not necessarily consecutive.

Note: this question is a variation of [How to remove dupes from blocks of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618467/how-to-remove-dupes-from-blocks-of-text) -- which is for blocks of text separated with blank lines.

Comment: Any time you post a "how to remove dups" question you should include a case where one word is a substring of the other in the sample input, e.g. `apple,pineapple` because more often than not people writing solutions won't consider that case unless its specifically part of the question. Also, if RE metacharactes can be present, e.g. `.`, `*`, `?`, etc. then include those too as people often propose regexp-based instead of string-based solutions and those are much trickier to get right when RE metachars can be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( split($0,t,$i)>2 ) sub($i",","") }1' file             
banana,apple,cherry
delta,epsilon
apple pie,delta
```

sed version:

```
sed -r 's/(.+)(.*),\1/\1\2,/g;s/,$//' file
apple,banana,cherry
delta,epsilon
apple pie,delta
```

Just Code.

Comment: wrt the awk version: Try that when you have both apple and pineapple each appear once on the same line and you'll find it deletes apple or truncates pineapple to pine, depending on their order on the line. You'd need to add gawk-specific word boundaries (which would only work if the chars in each field are word-constituent) or some other delimiters and then it would still fail if any regexp meta-character appeared in a field.  It also doesn't produce output in the desired order because it deletes the first occurrences of each string, not the subsequent ones. The sed has some similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    delete seen
    sep=""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (!seen[$i]++) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $i
            sep = OFS
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
apple,banana,cherry
delta,epsilon
apple pie,delta
```

Comment: No one-liner? I suppose it could be a one-liner by piping through tr before/after.

Comment: Ed Morton script in one line `awk -v OFS="," -F"," '{ delete seen; sep=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (!seen[$i]++) {printf "%s%s", sep, $i; sep = OFS} print ""}' file`

Comment: You can always cram any awk script onto one line by adding semi-colons at the end of every line that doesn't end in `{` or `}` but in my experience that creates an illegible mess for zero benefit.

Comment: The problem is something easy to maintain and modify down the road. Ed's solution to a variant of this problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618467/how-to-remove-dupes-from-blocks-of-text) was so elegant, that for my purpose I converted this delimited format (with the commas) to/from the one-per-line format (with tr and/or sed). That results in a piped one-lier which is very easy to read.

Comment: If you were going to throw in trs and seds just to keep it on one line you might have been better off with the less clear (than the above) and gawk specific: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="[,\n]"} !seen[$0]++{r=r s $0; s=","} RT=="\n"{print r; r=s=""; delete seen}' file`